# How to delete all Persistent variables when a page is loaded?

Tags: 7, configuration

I have many variables set through variable_set. Is there any other way to delete them all at once apart from variable_del?

or How can find all the persistent variables set in the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considered bad practice to delete all the persistent variables whose name starts with the short name of the module. There could be a module whose short name starts with that short name; in that case you would be removing the persistent variables of that module.
For example, given the Views module, there could be a Views Enhancer module. Deleting all the persistent variable matching the SQL pattern `'%views_%'` would mean deleting the persistent variables of both modules.

Instead, you should have a list of all the persistent variables your module uses. (That is not hard, since you are writing the code of your module.) Using that list (for example, contained in `$variables`), a code like the following would delete all the variables.

```
  global $conf;

  db_delete('variable')
    ->condition('name', $variables, 'IN')
    ->execute();
  cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');

  foreach ($variables as $name) {
    unset($conf[$name]); 
  }
```

This is, essentially, the code of [`variable_del()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_del/7.x) adapted to delete a list of variable names contained in `$variables`.

You could also use that code to implement a function your module uses.

```
function variable_delete_multiple(array $variables) {
  global $conf;

  db_delete('variable')
    ->condition('name', $variables, 'IN')
    ->execute();
  cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');

  foreach ($variables as $name) {
    unset($conf[$name]); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use MySQL to delete persistent variables set by [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x):

`delete from variable where name like '%module_name_variable_name%';`

but assuming that you want to delete those variables on every page load consider another way to implement your code than using variable_get which is using the caching system